# Hardware supporting openCl 2.0?

Tags: opencl

Is there any hardware supporting openCL 2.0? If yes then please tell me company of the hardware,name of the product and if possible specification of that hardware). Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

*(update October 2014)*

We now have conformant OpenCL 2.0 implementations available from both Intel and AMD. The [Khronos conformant OpenCL products page](https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products) shows that AMD has quite a few GPUs that can run OpenCL 2.0. It's not clear exactly which devices Intel support OpenCL 2.0 on at the moment, although their Core M processors are explicitly called out on their [OpenCL page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl).

---

*(original answer May 2014)*

At present, there are no conformant implementations of OpenCL 2.0 available.

In terms of hardware support, AMD have stated that some of their latest GPUs have the capabilities for OpenCL 2.0, and I would expect that most (if not all) modern CPUs have too (Xeon Phi likely does as well). NVIDIA's latest GPUs are probably also compliant, since they have CUDA equivalents of nested parallelism and SVM.

So, we are just waiting for the actual implementations (i.e. drivers) to appear. At IWOCL'14 last week it was mentioned that the conformance package for OpenCL 2.0 was only just finalised recently, so we can expect to see these implementations start to appear in the coming months.

In the meantime, AMD have preliminary support for some OpenCL 2.0 already available in their latest [beta driver](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-tools-sdks/opencl-1-2-beta-driver/).

Comment: I would be skeptical that nVidia supports OCL 2.0, as they don't even fully support OCL 1.2 yet.

Comment: I would be skeptical that nVidia supports OCL 2.0, as they don't even fully support OCL 1.2 yet.

Answer (score 0):

As of a few days now, Intel's HD Graphics 5300 in the new Core M processors do support OpenCL 2.0. They also have a CPU driver for all Intel processors, what I believe should also run on AMD processors.

No desktop versions of these processors are available yet, Acer, ASUS, Dell, HP, and Lenovo announced laptops and tablets based on them.

- [Intel SDK for OpenCL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl)
- [Specifications of Intel Core M processors](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/83613/Intel-Core-M-Processors)

Comment: See [https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/532670](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/532670) to see the support of Intel hardware. It's indeed Intel's HD Graphics 5300.